# Compile time function ptr dereference

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Hi I have the following design and I wonder if in general a C compiler (gcc or clang) will attempt to resolve the function pointer at compile time or will it always leave it till run time.

In test.h:

```
typedef struct array_ {
  size_t size;
  void *array;
  size_t (*get_size)(struct array_ *);
} array_t;

static inline size_t
get_size (array_t *A) {
  return A->get_size(A);
}
```

In test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

static size_t _get_size (array_t *A) {
  return A->size;
}

int main(void)
{
  array_t *A = malloc(sizeof(array_t));

  A->size = 3;
  A->array = (int[]){1,2,3};
  A->get_size = _get_size;

  printf("%llu\n", A->get_size(A));
  printf("%llu\n", get_size(A));
  return 0;
}
```

My question is - would A->get_size(A) be resolved at compile time to _get_size(A) or maybe even to A->size? Is A->get_size() always more efficient than get_size(A) or do they compile to pretty much the same thing?

I realize I'm asking about what a compiler will or won't do which is dependent on the compiler and other things (e.g. optimisation level) but in general is there an answer or does it just depend on too many things?

Edit: I have omitted error checking for clarity.

EDIT: "gcc -S" code. I think a pointer is being dereferenced.

```
main:
.LFB4:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    $24, %edi
        call    malloc
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    $3, (%rax)
        movl    $1, -16(%rbp)
        movl    $2, -12(%rbp)
        movl    $3, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, 8(%rax)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    $_get_size, 16(%rax)
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    16(%rax), %rax
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rdi
        call    *%rax
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    get_size
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: as you correctly observe, "it depends". You might try using the `-S` compiler option (compile to assembly) with various levels of optimization options and look at the resulting assembly code to see what the compiler does in each case. (EDIT: this is for gcc. I do not know what flags to give to clang).

Comment: I did this. "clang -S" is same as "gcc -S". Above is the gcc disassembly (no optimisation). clang produces very different disassembly and even more different with "-O3".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how clang implements the `main` function at maximum optimization

```
; function prologue
0xa071:  pushl  %ebp                    ; save the base pointer
0xa072:  movl   %esp, %ebp              ; setup new base pointer
0xa074:  pushl  %esi                    ; save esi register
0xa075:  subl   $0x14, %esp             ; reserve 20 bytes

; compute the address of the format string "%llu\n"
0xa078:  calll  0xa07d                  ; put the PC on the stack
0xa07d:  popl   %eax                    ; put the PC into eax
0xa07e:  leal   0x6f8e(%eax), %esi      ; esi points to the format string

; first call to printf
0xa084:  movl   %esi, (%esp)            ; put the format string on the stack
0xa087:  movl   $0x3, 0x4(%esp)         ; put the precomputed size on the stack
0xa08f:  calll  0xc674                  ; call printf

; second call to printf
0xa094:  movl   %esi, (%esp)            ; put the format string on the stack
0xa097:  movl   $0x3, 0x4(%esp)         ; put the precomputed size on the stack
0xa09f:  calll  0xc674                  ; call printf

; function epilogue
0xa0a4:  xorl   %eax, %eax              ; return value is 0
0xa0a6:  addl   $0x14, %esp             ; clean up the stack
0xa0a9:  popl   %esi                    ; restore esi register
0xa0aa:  popl   %ebp                    ; restore the base pointer
0xa0ab:  ret                            ; done
```

At maximum optimization, clang goes well beyond resolving the function pointer at compile time. It removes *all* of the code related to the structure.

- it doesn't bother to call `malloc`
- it doesn't generate any code to initialize the structure
- it precomputes the results of `A->get_size(A)`
- it precomputes the results of `get_size(A)`

So the code in `main` is essentially reduced to

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%llu\n", 3 );
    printf("%llu\n", 3 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you just assigned the function pointer one line above where you use it, good compilers like gcc and clang should be smart enough to resolve it at compile time.  But once you start passing pointers to that struct around between different functions that are in different files they almost certainly won't resolve it at compile time.

If you want to know your compiler in such detail you should start looking at the disassembly listings.

If you want to use syntax like that in your example code and have it be compiled efficiently, C++ is a fine language.